# Replacing RAILS_ROOT with Rails.root

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to replace the deprecated RAILS_ROOT with Rails.root as part of the process of getting the application ready to upgrade to Rails 3.
The application is currently running with version 2.3.14 and was originally created in 1.2

At the beginning of my boot.rb file is the line:

RAILS_ROOT = "#{File.dirname(**FILE**)}/.." unless defined?(RAILS_ROOT)

I cant just substitute Rails.root here as Rails is undefined.

What is the recommended way of setting Rails.root?

I dont think I made the question clear enough.

- I am aware that Rails.root already exists in Rails 2.
- I can use Rails.root in my code quite happily.
- BUT I dont know how to SET Rails.root at startup. I currently appears
  to be set right at the top of boot.rb with the line:

  RAILS_ROOT = "#{File.dirname(**FILE**)}/.." unless defined?(RAILS_ROOT)
- I CANT just change that line to use Rails.root as I will get the
  error:

  ../config/boot.rb:3: uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)

Thanks
George

Comment: Did you ever solve the problem?

Comment: I think I just ended up leaving the code with RAILS_ROOT in it until I upgraded to Rails 3. None of the answers really suggested how I could get rid of it. I could replace RAILS_ROOT with Rails.root everywhere else but not in that line in Boot.rb.

Comment: Interesting, I had the same issue in rails 3.2.14. Never found a solution

Comment: boot.rb change in Rails 3.2. You should use the new boot.rb that doesn't require you to setup RAILS_ROOT.

Answer (score 13):

You can use like this

```
 Rails.root.join('lib/ca-bundle.crt')
```

try it

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this does not answer the question either. I have expanded the question to make it clearer.

Comment: But it solved my problem , as I was upgrading from rails 2.3.5 app to 3.2.11.  THANKS

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `Rails.root` actually existed in Rails 2.3: http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.2/Rails/root/class

And in 2.3, it just returns `RAILS_ROOT`, so unless I'm mistaken, you can just use `Rails.root` in your code without other modifications. When you do the upgrade, your `boot.rb` will be replaced, as will the `Rails` module, so you code should continue to work properly.

Also, in case you're not using it already, my colleagues and I found this plugin **extremely** helpful when upgrading from 2.3 to 3.0 a little while back: https://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade

Comment: @giorgio But `Rails.root` just returns `RAILS_ROOT`, like I said. So, if you change the value of `RAILS_ROOT`, you'll change the value of `Rails.root`. Is there some reason that doesn't fit what you want to do?

Comment: I guess I just leave the RAILS_ROOT constant in then... I assumed that as it is deprecated I should completely remove it and not assume that setting RAILS_ROOT would magically set Rails.root. I guess when I upgrade to Rails 3 then the boot.rb etc will be regenerated anyway.

Comment: That's exactly right. Don't expect to manually set core methods. Take a look at the plugin I linked to. It replaces all the files that need replacing and also gives you a ton of tips on what parts of your code need to change. Also, check out the Railscast on the topic here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1